# Gridview in javascript, identifying a series of numbers

Tags: javascript

Given this sample grid and a number `n`:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
```

i want to select 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12... so on and so forth.

the odd numbers, you can use `modulus %2 == 1`

for the rest how do you do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? At the moment your question feels like your homework... Also what is your "grid"? Is it nested arrays, or a string, etc?

Comment: it is a listview actually. im a bit rusty in modulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a test, which skips a modulo 3 value, moved by an offset.

```js
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % 3) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if OP is using nested arrays. Also, it feels like their just wanting us to do their homework...

Answer (score 1):

if you had an array of arrays structure you could transpose the grid and choose row 0 and 2:

```js
var d = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12]
]

const trans = a => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(z => z[i]))

console.log(trans(d)[0], trans(d)[2])
```